# Контекстное меню для WebView в Android

Tags: menu, android, java, webview

Есть `WebView` с загруженным в него Html документом, требуется по долгому тапу показать контекстное меню. Многие наверное замечали, что в `WebView` обычный метод  с `registerForContextMenu(textview);` не работает (контекстное меню появляется, но только при тапе на ссылках).
Искал, нашел что-то похожее на решение, но воспроизвести не смог: [Android: Opening a ContextMenu from onLongPress in custom WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882025/android-opening-a-contextmenu-from-onlongpress-in-custom-webview)

У меня код падает на `MyWebView`:

```
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent event) {
    theListener.onLongClick(MyWebView.this);
}
```

с сообщением в

```
LogCat: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Вот код:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

MyWebView mWebView;
public static final int IDM_OPEN = 101; 
public static final int IDM_SAVE = 102; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (MyWebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/docs/pue.html");
    mWebView.setLongClickable(true);
    registerForContextMenu(mWebView);
}

public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    openContextMenu(v);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    // Операции для выбранного пункта меню
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {
    case R.id.menu_settings:
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                "Long Click",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) 
{
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, IDM_OPEN, Menu.NONE, "Открыть");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, IDM_SAVE, Menu.NONE, "Сохранить");
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Так, разобрался!

Все решилось добавлением "магической" строчки:

```
mWebView.theListener = this;
```

после загрузки файла в `mWebView`

Правда, как и у автора вопроса на стековерфлоу выше теперь документ не мотается., но это уже другой вопрос.